# Not getting any result out of my SwiftUI Picker for a complex type

Tags: swiftui, picker

I wanted to use a SwiftUI `Picker` for a complex type. I see the picker and I can select a value, but I never get the `didSet` output and `category` always stays nil. Any suggestions?

```
struct EntryView: View {
    @State private var category: UUID? = UUID() { 
        didSet {
            print("category changed to \(category!)")
        }
    }

    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Category.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Category.title, ascending: true)
        ]

    ) var categories: FetchedResults<Category>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker("Meter", selection: $category) {
                        ForEach(categories) { cat in
                            Text(cat.title ?? "")
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }    
    }

}
```

Comment: `didSet` does not work for @State, because value is stored outside of View. Why just not use `category` and how did you determine that it is `nil`?

Comment: i have a button so save the value, and in the debugger the value of category is showing nil